# Setting Custom Paper Size in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

here is the code

$pdf = new PDF('P','mm',array(210,148.5));

we are trying to achieve A4 half size

but not getting desired result

Comment: Make sure the constructor of `PDF` (if it exists) forwards the parameters to the parent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this [documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/__construct.htm).

It should be `FPDF` instead of `PDF`?

Try this out:

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm',array(210,148.5));
```